# Gradient with $v_1 := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2 := \frac{1}{5} \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix} $ given

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

Let $g: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be totally differentiable in the point $a \in \mathbb{R^2}$.

Let $v_1 := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2 := \frac{1}{5} \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix} $ be normalized direction vectors in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

It is $\frac{\partial g}{\partial v_1} (a) = 5 \sqrt{2}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial v_2} (a) = 1$.

With the info given above, how can one find out $\nabla g(a)$?

We don't know what the function $g$ looks like and we also don't know the point $a$.
So, there must be some kind of "reverse approach" to get the gradient of that function, but I don't know how we can do that.

Comment: Recall the definition of directional derivative. How does it relate to the gradient? If you haven't seen such a relation try to derive it yourself by comparing the definitions of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are unit vectors, the the direction derivative gives

$\nabla_{v_1} g = \nabla g \cdot v_1 $

and

$\nabla_{v_2} g = \nabla g \cdot v_2 $

Use these to build a linear system of 2 equations in the 2 components of $\nabla g$, and solve.  So, if

$\nabla g = [x, y]^T $, then

$ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} x + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} y = 5 \sqrt{2} $

and

$ \dfrac{4}{5} x - \dfrac{3}{5} y = 1 $

After multiplying the first equation through by $\sqrt{2}$ and second equation by $5$, they becomes

$ x + y = 10 $

$ 4 x - 3 y = 5 $

It is trivial to solve to get $ x = 5 $ , $ y = 5 $

Therefore, $ \nabla g = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix} $